# " Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException"

Tags: java

How can I show the Output of this Program? When I run it, it will throw an `InputMismatchException`.

Here is the entire code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Try {

    static HashMap< String, String> codeMap = new HashMap< String, String>();
    static HashMap< String, String> ref = new HashMap< String, String>();

    static void initMap() {
        codeMap.put("A", ".-");
        codeMap.put("B", "-...");
        codeMap.put("C", "-.-.");
        codeMap.put("D", "-..");
        codeMap.put("E", ".");
        codeMap.put("F", "..-.");
        codeMap.put("G", "--.");
        codeMap.put("H", "....");
        codeMap.put("I", "..");
        codeMap.put("J", ".---");
        codeMap.put("K", "-.-");
        codeMap.put("L", ".-..");
        codeMap.put("M", "--");
        codeMap.put("N", "-.");
        codeMap.put("O", "---");
        codeMap.put("P", ".--.");
        codeMap.put("Q", "--.-");
        codeMap.put("R", ".-.");
        codeMap.put("S", "...");
        codeMap.put("T", "-");
        codeMap.put("U", "..-");
        codeMap.put("V", "...-");
        codeMap.put("W", ".--");
        codeMap.put("X", "-..-");
        codeMap.put("Y", "-.--");
        codeMap.put("Z", "--..");
        codeMap.put("_", "..--");
        codeMap.put(".", "---.");
        codeMap.put(",", ".-.-");
        codeMap.put("?", "----");

        ref.put(".-", "A");
        ref.put("-...", "B");
        ref.put("-.-.", "C");
        ref.put("-..", "D");
        ref.put(".", "E");
        ref.put("..-.", "F");
        ref.put("--.", "G");
        ref.put("....", "H");
        ref.put("..", "I");
        ref.put(".---", "J");
        ref.put("-.-", "K");
        ref.put(".-..", "L");
        ref.put("--", "M");
        ref.put("-.", "N");
        ref.put("---", "O");
        ref.put(".--.", "P");
        ref.put("--.-", "Q");
        ref.put(".-.", "R");
        ref.put("...", "S");
        ref.put("-", "T");
        ref.put("..-", "U");
        ref.put("...-", "V");
        ref.put(".--", "W");
        ref.put("-..-", "X");
        ref.put("-.--", "Y");
        ref.put("--..", "Z");
        ref.put("..--", "_");
        ref.put("---.", ".");
        ref.put(".-.-", ",");
        ref.put("----", "?");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Code: ");
            initMap();
            int N = in.nextInt();
            for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
                StringBuffer encry =  new StringBuffer(in.next());
                StringBuffer inter = new StringBuffer();
                StringBuffer num = new StringBuffer();

                StringBuffer org = new StringBuffer();
                String tmp =  new String(encry);
                for(int j = 0; j < tmp.length(); j++) {
                    inter.append(codeMap.get(tmp.substring(j, j+1)));
                    num.append(codeMap.get(tmp.substring(j, j+1)).length());       
                }
                num = num.reverse();
                int index = 0;
                for(int j = 0; j < num.length(); j++) {
                    int t1 = Integer.valueOf(num.substring(j, j+1));
                    StringBuffer con = new StringBuffer();
                    for(int k = index; k < index+t1;k++) {
                        con.append(inter.substring(k, k+1));
                    }
                    org.append(ref.get(new String(con)));
                    index += t1;
                }
                System.out.printf("%d: %s\n",i,org);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't show the output until you get your program to run. What line does the exception get thrown at?

Comment: The Program is running, but this shows error line 93 "int N = in.nextInt(); " when I enter it the input, then it will show 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException"
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at Try.main(Try.java:93)

Comment: @DaNiel What exactly is the input you are entering? If it isn't an `Integer`, then it's going to throw an exception...

Comment: for example this "AKADTOF_IBOETATUK_IJN" Converting to Morse code with a length string yields it will translate it into "ACM_GREATER_NY_REGION"

Comment: Are you entering the correct input? You could get that exception when you enter something that is not an integer

Comment: This problem requires that you implement Ohaver's encoding algorithm. The
 * input will consist of several messages encoded with Ohaver's algorithm.first line of the input is an integer n that specifies the number of test
 * cases. The following n lines contain one message per line. Each message will
 * use only the twenty-six capital letters, underscores, commas, periods, and
 * question marks. Messages will not exceed 100 characters in length.

Comment: I took the liberty to properly indent your code. Turns out there is a useless `{}` block wrapping the body of your `main()` method. Doesn't hurt but there is also no reason for it and it goes to show that you should probably pay some more attention to the formatting of your code even in your IDE.

Comment: Thank You for All Your Help :) I Got it :D

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the whole code in a try block and print the stack trace in the catch block and see on which line there is error and act accordingly.

Comment: how can i do that sir?

Comment: Now there's no need as you have already said that error in in line 93. I think you are not entering an integer, and therefore getting this error.

Comment: Okay Sir Thanks For the Help :)